# g++ is unable to find my header file

Tags: c++, compilation, g++, header-files

I'm trying to compile the file *q1.cpp* but I keep getting the compilation error:

```
q1.cpp:2:28: fatal error: SavingsAccount.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

The header file and the implementation of the header file are both in the exact same directory as *q1.cpp*.

The files are as follows:

*q1.cpp*:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SavingsAccount.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    SavingsAccount s1(2000.00);
    SavingsAccount s2(3000.00);
}
```

*SavingsAccount.cpp*:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SavingsAccount.h>
using namespace std;

//constrauctor
SavingsAccount::SavingsAccount(double initialBalance) {
     savingsBalance = initialBalance;
}
SavingsAccount::calculateMonthlyInterest() {
     return savingsBalance*annualInterestRate/12
}
SavingsAccount::modifyInterestRate(double new_rate) {
     annualInterestRate = new_rate;
}
```

*SavingsAccount.h*:

```
class SavingsAccount {
    public:
        double annualInterestRate;
        SavingsAccount(double);
        double calculateMonthlyInterest();
        double modifyInterestRate(double);
    private:
        double savingsBalance;
};
```

I'd like to reiterate that all files are in the SAME directory. I'm trying to compile by using this line at a windows command prompt:

```
 C:\MinGW\bin\g++ q1.cpp -o q1
```

Any input into this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Only system-builtin headers are used as `#include <headername>`. Your own custom headers, except for those copied to the system include path (which is not recommended), must be used as `#include "myheader.h"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 #include <SavingsAccount.h>
```

should be

```
#include "SavingsAccount.h"
```

since `SavingsAccount.h` is the header file you defined, you should not ask the compiler to search for system headers by using `<>` around it.

Meanwhile, when you compile it, you should compile both cpp files: `SavingsAccount.cpp` and `q1.cpp`.

```
 g++ SavingsAccount.cpp q1.cpp -o q1
```

BTW: you missed a `;` here:

```
SavingsAccount::calculateMonthlyInterest() {
    return savingsBalance*annualInterestRate/12;
                                    //^^; cannot miss it
}
```

Comment: Also, shouldn't he compile `SavingsAccount.cpp` and link it as well?

Comment: Ahh, that's it! Can't believe I missed that... thanks, will accept this answer as correct when I'm able to.

Comment: I have to wait another 7 minutes before I'm able apparently.